# Remove osascript starting after boot and get to know what it does

Tags: macos, applescript, script

I am new to Mac and I have the following problem. After I log in after boot/restart, there is always a tab saying `osascript wants to make changes` which wants my password. I do not want to run this and clicking `Cancel` or killing this process in Activity monitor helps for the session. I am also able to see the details of it in Activity monitor. But regardless of what I do, after another start, the pop up menu appears again... How can I kill this script or remove it or disable it forever?

Related to that, how do I get to know what exactly is it trying to do? I tried to hit the `Sample` button in the menu in Activity monitor which gave me a text file of many things starting with the dirs and identifiers of the script and continuing with a lot of information which I don't know how to read/interpret (see below). As I said, I'm new to Mac so any help including the super basics is very welcomed :).
Thank you.

---

EDIT:

Following the comments:
Both `cd Library/LaunchAgents; grep 'osascript' *.plist` and `cd /Library/LaunchAgents; grep 'osascript' *.plist` output nothing. When I go to the process in Activity monitor and go to the `Open files and ports`, I get the following:

```
cwd
/
txt
/usr/bin/osascript
txt
/Library/Preferences/Logging/.plist-cache.xq4DHtYC
txt
/private/var/db/analyticsd/events.whitelist
txt
/System/Library/MessageTracer/SubmitDiagInfo.default.domains.searchtree
txt
/System/Library/Components/AppleScript.component/Contents/MacOS/AppleScript
txt
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/HIToolbox.rsrc
txt
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/Localized.rsrc
txt
/private/var/db/mds/messages/502/se_SecurityMessages
txt
/usr/share/icu/icudt64l.dat
txt
/private/var/db/timezone/tz/2020a.1.0/icutz/icutz44l.dat
txt
/System/Library/Keyboard Layouts/AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle/Contents/Resources/AppleKeyboardLayouts-L.dat
txt
/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.IntlDataCache.le.kbdx
txt
/System/Library/ScriptingAdditions/StandardAdditions.osax/Contents/MacOS/StandardAdditions
txt
/usr/lib/dyld
0
/dev/null
1
/dev/null
2
/dev/null
3
/System/Library/MessageTracer/SubmitDiagInfo.default.domains.searchtree
4
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/HIToolbox.rsrc
5
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/Localized.rsrc
```

If needed, I also have clicked the `Sample` button. That gives this followed by `Call graph` section (not shown here):

```
Sampling process 680 for 3 seconds with 1 millisecond of run time between samples
Sampling completed, processing symbols...
Analysis of sampling osascript (pid 680) every 1 millisecond
Process:         osascript [680]
Path:            /usr/bin/osascript
Load Address:    0x1019b7000
Identifier:      osascript
Version:         395.1
Code Type:       X86-64
Parent Process:  bash [508]

Date/Time:       2020-10-22 10:14:04.108 +0300
Launch Time:     2020-10-22 08:27:11.218 +0300
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.15.7 (19H2)
Report Version:  7
Analysis Tool:   /usr/bin/sample

Physical footprint:         4844K
Physical footprint (peak):  5056K
```

---

The output for:

```
ps auxwww | grep '[o]sascript'
```

when the pop up window is still active (presumably what you mean by it running) is:

```
jan                680   0.0  0.0  5765928   9756   ??  S     8:27AM   0:00.15 osascript -e do shell script "/Library/Scripts/WIS/tmp/Scripts/startup.sh" with administrator privileges
```

Is this the script what it is calling? What does it do?

Comment: Have a look at **Add or remove automatic items** in [Open items automatically when you log in on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/open-items-automatically-when-you-log-in-mh15189/mac). If it's not there, then it may be in `~Library/LaunchAgents` or `/Library/LaunchAgents`

Comment: Hi, there I have already looked, it is not an app so it does not show up in the Login items. About the `Library`, how do I get to know if it is in `LaunchAgents`? There are many `com.` files but I do not know which one is associated with the osascript.

Comment: Open **Terminal**, which by default opens to your **Home** _directory_, and run the following _compound command_: `cd Library/LaunchAgents; grep 'osascript' *.plist` and if that doesn't output anything useful, try: `cd /Library/LaunchAgents; grep 'osascript' *.plist`

Comment: Those commands are the same but even if the other should be with `~`, it gives nothing.

Comment: Those _commands_ are not the same if **Terminal** opens to the _default directory_! The first one changes to `Library/LaunchAgents` in the _current directory_, which should be your **Home** _directory_ and the second one is to the one in the _root_ of the **Macintosh HD**.

Comment: Since you can see the _process_ in **Activity Monitor**, do the following... Log out and back in so as to trigger the _process_ and without clicking the **Cancel** button, go into **Activity Monitor**, find the _process_, click the information button and then on the **Open Files an Ports** _tab_, copy it... and then edit your question, pasting in the information.

Comment: Sorry, my bad vision spoke... Anyway, the results hold. I updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: With the _process_ active, what is the output of the following in **Terminal**: `ps auxwww | grep '[o]sascript'`

Comment: Out of curiosity..is this your own personal computer or something that your employer provided?  If the latter is it managed in any way?

Comment: RE: "Is this the script what it is calling? What does it do?" -- Yes, that's the target and can't say what's it's doing without seeing what's in it.  What's the output in **Terminal** of `cat /Library/Scripts/WIS/tmp/Scripts/startup.sh`

Comment: @Allan - the latter and no, it should not be managed by anyone except for me. @user3239894 thank you very much. I believe it would probably be better for another question but besides writing a log and restarting, this is the main part: `##Caffeinate
/usr/bin/caffeinate -dis &
caffeinatePID=$!

ImagePKG="/Library/Scripts/WIS/tmp/Scripts/UpdateUser.pkg"

/usr/sbin/installer -dumplog -verbose -pkg "$ImagePKG" -target /`. The pkg is a binary file.

Comment: The reason I asked is because what you're describing is outside the norm for a personal computer but indicative of something that's managed.  Now, it being "managed by only you," is that your opinion on the matter or is that policy?  Either way, that looks like something installed by your IT department.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the parent process of osascript is 'bash', that suggests that a command line script is calling AppleScript.

```
/Library/Scripts/WIS/tmp/Scripts/startup.sh
```

is very likely the culprit.

Have you installed anything that this might relate to?

If not, I would delete it, and download [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/) to check for malware.